# Odometer in react-native gives document not found error

Tags: react-native

I want show stopwatch in my react-native app so I installed [odometer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odometer) library but its throwing error `document is not defined`. How do I solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you have this error? at runtime or when you build the app?

Comment: As per the docs its a library for the web not for react native refer the docs https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

Comment: I get error on runtime @vincenzopalazzo

Comment: Is there any other way I can achieve same result ? @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: @Jits i dont see possible alternative library for react native but there is one for speedo meter not odometer